# Python Warning control

Tags: python, warnings

I would like some kind of warning to be raisen as errors, but only the first occurrence. How to do that?

I read http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html and I dont know how to combine this two types of behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the code to warnings.py, you can't assign more than one filter action to a warning, and you can't (easily) define your own actions, like 'raise_once'.

However, if you want to raise a warning as an exception, but just once, that means that you are catching the exception. Why not put a line in your except clause that sets an 'ignore' action on that particular warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error','Test')
for i in range(2):
  try:
    warnings.warn('Test');
  except UserWarning, e:
    print "Error caught"
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore','Test')
```

Comment: Is there a way to make warnings mute after few similar warnings? I mean after exact number of same warnings.

Comment: L1ker, See http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter. You can e.g. call `warnings.filterwarnings("once")` somewhere before the warnings are raised. However, there is no way to show the same warning more than once but a fixed number of times, as you ask.